# R Brackets in plot above certain points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Let's assume I have some data and want to insert a bracket over certain points, e.g., using the `geom_bracket()` function from the `ggpubr` package. Assuming that the y-axis is numeric, this works fine.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 value = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, y.position = 4, 
               label = "label")
```

[image: output]

However, once the y-axis is no longer numeric but of the class character as well, the procedure no longer works and throws the following error message: `` Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_bracket()` Caused by error in `yrange[2] - yrange[1]`: ! non-numeric argument to binary operator ``. Is there a solution to fix this problem? Converting the variable to a factor does not seem to fix the problem.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 y = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
                 value = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(xmin = 1, xmax = 3, y.position = 4, 
               label = "label")
```

The value column is only required when one uses, e.g., `geom_tile(aes(fill = (value)))` instead of `geom_point()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to convert the variable mapped on `y` to a `numeric` and to use a continuous y scale. Afterwards you could use the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous` to get the proper labels:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  y = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
  value = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
)

# Convert to numerics
df$y_num <- as.numeric(factor(df$y))
# Breaks and Labels
breaks <- unique(df$y_num)
labels <- setNames(unique(df$y), breaks)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y_num)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(
    xmin = 1, xmax = 3, y.position = 4,
    label = "label"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
```

[image]